# Remove Line If Value In Column Matches Value In A Separate List

Tags: awk

I have one file like this:

```
george@mail.com|george|Sutherland|Manchester|England
marcel@email.com|Marcel|ZIDANE|Marseille|France
some@gmail.com|Simon|surname|Somewhere|Else
```

And a list of emails:

```
ty230923@hotmail.com
marcel@email.com
email@anothermail.com
```

I would like to remove all lines from file 1 which contain an email in the first column found in file 2. Expected output would be as follows:

```
george@mail.com|george|Sutherland|Manchester|England
some@gmail.com|Simon|surname|Somewhere|Else
```

I need a solution that will work at a large scale (100,000,000's of lines). Have tried a grep solution but after hours of running there was still no result. Have been advised that AWK might be the way to go.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: An awk solution would be more robust but it wouldn't be faster than a grep solution, sorry. I find it hard to believe any reasonable grep solution would run for hours on that though. Post what you tried so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use the pandas library with the merge function to obtain what you want. You shouldn't have any problem with scaling using pandas.

Here is how you would resolve the problem :

```
import pandas

In [1] : df = pd.DataFrame({'e-mail': ['a@hotmail.fr', 'b@hotmail.fr', 'c@hotmail.fr'], "Name": ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Britney']})
Out[1] :
Name    e-mail
0   Bob a@hotmail.fr
1   Alice   b@hotmail.fr
2   Britney c@hotmail.fr

In [2] : df2 = pd.DataFrame({'e-mail' : ['a@hotmail.fr', 'd@hotmail.fr']})
Out[2] :
e-mail
0   a@hotmail.fr
1   d@hotmail.fr

In [3] : df_ final = df.merge(df2, indicator='i', how='outer').query('i == "left_only"').drop('i', 1)

In [4]: df_final.head()
Out[4]: 
Name    e-mail
1   Alice   b@hotmail.fr
2   Britney c@hotmail.fr
```